# How to get column name and data type returned by a custom query in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How to get column name and data type returned by a custom query in postgres? We have inbuilt functions   for table/views but not for custom queries. For more clarification I would say that I need a postgres function which will take sql string as parameter and will return colnames and their datatype.

Comment: There might be a better way, but I would probably create a temp table and query from that for convenience :)

Comment: Thanks Wolph...but what if I use it in a web application and there may be 1000 requests creating 1000 tables (If I manage to have different names)..then it will be not much practical

Comment: In Java, there is a way to query the database to retrieve the database's metadata. What are you using?

Comment: @DavidBrossard yes..thats right..that is a way..but I want to do it in database side

Comment: A quick bit of Google took me to this thing: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050119055056.GA56810%40winnie.fuhr.org

Comment: @BLGupta: No need to worry about that if you bind the temporary table to your transaction. As soon as the transaction is gone the table will disappear as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in SQL function which does this for you.

If you want to do this purely at the SQL level, the simplest and cheapest way is probably to `CREATE TEMP VIEW AS (<your_query>)`, dig the column definitions out of the catalog tables, and drop the view when you're done. However, this can have a non-trivial overhead depending on how often you do it (as it needs to write view definitions to the catalogs), can't be run in a read-only transaction, and can't be done on a standby server.

The ideal solution, if it fits your use case, is to build a prepared query on the client side, and make use of the metadata returned by the server (in the form of a `RowDescription` message passed as part of the [query protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY)). Unfortunately, this depends very much on which client library you're using, and how much of this information it chooses to expose. For example, `libpq` will give you access to [everything](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-SELECT-INFO), whereas the JDBC driver limits you to the public methods on its [`ResultSetMetadata`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgResultSetMetaData.html#getPGType-int-) object (though you could probably pull more information from its private fields via reflection, if you're determined enough).

If you want a read-only, low-overhead, client-independent solution, then you could also write a server-side [C function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html) to prepare and describe the query via [SPI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi.html). Writing and building C functions comes with a bit of a learning curve, but you can find numerous examples on [PGXN](https://pgxn.org/), or within Postgres' own [contrib modules](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib).

Comment: perhaps your answer is the most accurate for time being. But my point is  psql executes query and then it displays records along with their col name and header...I was just wondering that if any way possible we could use that in-built function to achieve the goal..

Comment: Ok then I will go for C Functions...Can you please guide me from where to start...I am confident in C but never developed for postgres

Comment: @BLGupta: (Sorry, accidentally posted that last comment before I finished it...) There's no built-in function, as far as I'm aware. I'm fairly sure that `psql` gets the column types from `libpq` as described above, and formats them on the client side. I think the relevant is [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/bin/psql/common.c#L1553).

Comment: @BLGupta: As for getting started... Install the dev package for your distro (e.g. `yum install postgresql96-devel` on RedHat), make sure `pg_config` is in your `PATH`, work through [this example](https://christian-rossow.de/articles/PostgreSQL_C_language_functions_with_bytea.php), and adapt the example function to your case. (Or if you're on Windows, read [this](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/).)

Comment: Note that the arguments and return values are all hidden behind macros (defined in `fmgr.h`) which handle the conversion to/from SQL types. Built-in functions are written against the same interface, so you can find plenty of examples in the Postgres source. The [SPI interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi.html) for describing queries is pretty well-documented.

Comment: The tricky part is probably building the result, as you need to return descriptions of multiple columns. You could build an array (see the C implementation of [`string_to_array()`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c#L4155) for an example), return multiple rows (e.g. [`generate_series()`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/backend/utils/adt/int8.c#L1249)), or if you want something (relatively) quick and easy, just build a delimited string and parse it client-side.

Comment: Thank you for guidance Nick :) Now I feel that I can do it.